Swift Actor and GCD Dispatch Queue Executor
This is with reference to AVCam sample code by Apple:
   actor CaptureService {

          // The app's capture session.
         private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        // A serial dispatch queue to use for capture control actions.
         private let sessionQueue = DispatchSerialQueue(label: "com.example.apple-samplecode.AVCam.sessionQueue")

       // Sets the session queue as the actor's executor.
        nonisolated var unownedExecutor: UnownedSerialExecutor {
            sessionQueue.asUnownedSerialExecutor()
        }
     ...
  }

And then later in the Actor code:
    // Set the controls delegate.
    captureSession.setControlsDelegate(controlsDelegate, queue: sessionQueue)

If I understand it correctly, the effect of this code is to make all isolated method calls and mutable state modification to effectively happen to sessionQueue by implicitly calling sessionQueue.sync(). Is my understanding correct or there is more to it?

It is highly likely that it uses sync, but this is implementation detail. The documentation doesn’t say and it is not open source so you don’t know for sure.

@Sweeper Assuming it usessync, is it a bad concurrency construct to use?
